# Is there a way to highlight multiple areas selected by a rectangle selector in python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a GUI in python. We have big datasets which we can plot. What I want is that when a user plots a dataset, I give them an option to create sub datasets. This is covered but I have a problem where a user can select multiple regions in a plot ( using rectangle selector ) and then when they click on a button I create a new dataset from the regions selected. The part where I have a problem is : Selecting these multiple regions using Rectangle Selector and storing their values. Any help would be great. Thanks!
In the code the onkey function sees what has been done on the plot.
If a user selects a region and presses enter, the datapoints are colored blue and I can even retrieve and store those points to create new datasets. The only problem is I do not know how to select multiple regions using rectangle selector and then color them all blue and retrieve them to store.

```
    def line_select_callback(self, eclick, erelease):
        """
        Line selection callback function.
        """
        # 'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
        self.x_start, self.y_start = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
        self.x_end, self.y_end = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata

        def scatter(self):
        """
        Plots all datapoints as a scatterplot.
        """

        def onkey(event):
            """
            Checks for different key events.
            """

            if event.key == 'enter':
                draw_selection()
            elif event.key == "u":
                self.x_selected, self.y_selected = np.array([]), np.array([])
                clearSelection()
                self.canvas.draw()

        def draw_selection():
            """
            Draws the selection in a dedicated color.
            """
            try:
                xMin, xMax = (self.x_start, self.x_end) if self.x_start < self.x_end else (
                    self.x_end, self.x_start)
                yMin, yMax = (self.y_start, self.y_end) if self.y_start < self.y_end else (
                    self.y_end, self.y_start)
                idx = (xMin < self.time) & (self.time < xMax) & (
                        yMin < self.data) & (self.data < yMax)
                x1 = (self.time[idx])
                y1 = (self.data[idx])
               
                self.x_selected, self.y_selected = x1, y1
                self.axes.plot(x1, y1, "b" + self.marker)
                self.axes.lines[-1].set_markeredgecolor('none')
                self.axes.lines[-1].set_alpha(self.alpha / 5)
                self.canvas.draw()
                self.plot_fit()
            except IndexError:
                return

        def clearSelection():
            """
            Clears the selection, if possible.
            """
            try:
                while len(self.axes.lines) > 1:
                    self.axes.lines.remove(self.axes.lines[-1])
                if self.histaxes:
                    self.histaxes.cla()
                    self.draw_hist()
                self.plot_fit()
                self.canvas.draw()
            except IndexError:
                pass

        self.axes.plot(self.time, self.data, "k" + self.marker)
        self.axes.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=np.max(self.time))
        self.axes.set_xlabel("Time [s]")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("Conductance [" + self.unit + "]")
     
        if len(self.x_selected):
            self.axes.plot(self.x_selected, self.y_selected, "b" + self.marker)
            self.axes.lines[-1].set_markeredgecolor('none')
            self.axes.lines[-1].set_alpha(self.alpha / 5)

        self.selector = RectangleSelector(self.axes, self.line_select_callback,
                                          drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                          button=[1, 3],
                                          spancoords='pixels',
                                          interactive=True)
```

Comment: Couldnt you be showing what youve tried so far? So that we can spot the mistake and help with it.

Comment: hey I just added the code. Sorry took some time as I have put the code first time here. Please ignore the indexing and spacing. This part of the code works perfectly. I just wanted to know how to expand this to the multiple region case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand how this is an issue with tkinter. I would assume it would be with the `RectangleSelector` class which is part of matplotlib?

Comment: yes there is no issue with tkinter. I am just looking for references regarding the rectangle selector to do the task. I could not find how to do this with rectangle selector

Comment: @MariyamKhan All right, thanks for removing the tag. To be clear, do you want several selection rectangles visually present on the screen at the same time, one for each user selection, or just that the selections be stored without implementing that visual change?

Comment: @MariyamKhan Could you possibly send all the code, or enough for it to run, so that it could be easier to reproduce and improve upon?